# How to write retrofit query for array for get method?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am handling

```
@GET("match-details/5-days")
fun callMatchDetails(@Query("competition_id[]", encoded = true) competitionIdList: List<String>
): Call<MatchDetailResponseModel>?
```

which is look like below url:

[https://baseurl.com/match-details/5-days?competition_id[]=1588&competition_id[]=1589&competition_id[]=1592](https://baseurl.com/match-details/5-days?competition_id%5B%5D=1588&competition_id%5B%5D=1589&competition_id%5B%5D=1592)

How I can make it look like value in array bracket, as below:

[https://baseurl.com/match-details/5-days?competition_id[0]=1588&competition_id[1]=1589&competition_id[2]=1592](https://baseurl.com/match-details/5-days?competition_id%5B0%5D=1588&competition_id%5B1%5D=1589&competition_id%5B2%5D=1592)

Any answer or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in three steps :

1- Use **QueryMap** instead of Query as follow:

```
 @GET("match-details/5-days")
    fun callMatchDetails(
        @QueryMap(encoded = true) map: Map<String, Int>
    ): Call<MatchDetailResponseModel>?
```

2- Map your competition id list to Map<String,Int> as follow :

```
        val ids = mutableListOf(123, 134, 156)
        val map = mutableMapOf<String,Int>()
        ids.forEachIndexed { index, id ->
            map["competition_id[$index]"] = id
        }
//mutableMapOf: {competition_id[0]=123, competition_id[1]=134, competition_id[2]=156}
```

3- Send map to callMatchDetails fun and you will make it look like follow :

```
https://baseurl.com/match-details/5-days?competition_id[0]=123&competition_id[1]=134&competition_id[2]=156
```